# Calling member of added classes with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, virtual, multiple-inheritance

I had 4 classes:

- List
- Base
- A
- B

I needed to add a class which extends the work of the classes A and B - L3. Classes NewA and NewB implement the function declared in L3.

```
class Base
{
     virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class A: virtual public Base
{
     void foo();
}
class B: virtual public Base
{
     void foo();
}

class L3: virtual public Base
{
     virtual void bar() = 0;
}
class NewA: public A, virtual public L3
{
     void bar();
}

class NewB: public B, virtual public L3
{
     void bar();
}
```

How can I call function bar() inside List?

**UPD**

First List contains objects A and B, but now there NewA and NewB

```
class List
{
    public:
        void append(Base *sh);
        void next();
        void setBegin();
        Base* curr();
        void out(std::ofstream &ofst);

    protected:
        std::list <Base*> container;
        std::list <Base*>::iterator iter;
}

void List:: next()
{
    iter++;
}

void List:: setBegin()
{
    iter = container.begin();
}

void List:: append(Base* sh)
{
    container.push_back(sh);
}

Base* List::curr()
{
    return *iter;
}

void List::out(ofstream &ofst)
{
    setBegin();
    for (int i=0; i<container.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"Out: "<< endl; // I need to call bar() at this line
        next();
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't show class `List`. That makes your question a bit tough to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Base` doesn't have method `bar()`, only `L3` (and its derived class) has.
So you can't call `bar()` from `Base`.

You may do the following:

```
Base* base = List.curr();
L3* l3 = dynamic_cast<L3*>(base); // l3 is non null if base is non null and IS a L3.

if (l3 != nullptr) {
    // base->bar(); // ILLEGAL
    l3->bar();
}
```

In the case you know that `Base` *IS* a `L3` you may use a `static_cast`:

```
NewA newA;
Base* base = &newA;
L3* l3 = static_cast<L3*>(base);

newA.bar();
// base->bar(); // ILLEGAL
l3->bar();
```